# Is it possible to recover pass passwords from backup?

Tags: encryption, passwords, gnupg

I was missing some passwords for some quite old accounts, when I remembered I'd made a backup of my drive at the time. There, I found a `~/.local/share/password-store` directory, in which my passwords were encrypted by the [`pass`](https://www.passwordstore.org/) password manager. I also found the `~/.gnupg` and `~/.local/share/gnupg` directories.

My question is: is it possible to decrypt and recover the passwords in the backup? It feels like it must, but my attempts to use `gpg --import` have been unsuccessful.

Comment: "Pass" is a decent password manager and without the "master" password, you are most unlikely to be able to recover your passwords.

Comment: I don't think there is a master password -- unless you mean the gnupg private key password (which I do remember).

Comment: I put master in quotes because I do not know what they call the main password. You need something like that if the password you remember does not work;

Comment: There is no master password. Passwords are encrypted with gpg, and I have the private key. My question is how to get pass running on my machine to read and decrypt the passwords in the backup using the key in the backup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **my attempts to use `gpg --import` have been unsuccessful.**
> **... is it possible to decrypt and recover the passwords in the backup?**

Yes, but I don't think `--import` is the right choice here.

Looking at the [description of the `pass` program](https://www.passwordstore.org/) is suggests it stores each password in a separate file encrupted with `gpg`. The files are in the `~/.password-store` subdirectory.

Looking at [the actual program](https://git.zx2c4.com/password-store/tree/src/password-store.sh), a shell script, I see

```bash
PREFIX="${PASSWORD_STORE_DIR:-$HOME/.password-store}"
    [...]
cmd_show() {
    [...]
    local path="$1"
    local passfile="$PREFIX/$path.gpg"
    [...]
    if [[ -f $passfile ]]; then
        if [[ $clip -eq 0 && $qrcode -eq 0 ]]; then
            pass="$($GPG -d "${GPG_OPTS[@]}" "$passfile" | $BASE64)" || exit $?
            echo "$pass" | $BASE64 -d
```

From which I believe you need to run `gpg -d ~/.password-store/name_of_file` and use whatever encryption key you have configured into GPG when you first initialised `pass` (using the `-init` option?)

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to properly restore everything.